# How to get HTML from tkhtmlview HTMLText after making some edits in Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm using `tkhtmlview` to display HTML text in my `Tkinter` GUI.

here is the code I use:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkhtmlview import HTMLText

window = Tk()

html_sample = "<p><strong>in love (with </strong>someone or something<strong>)</strong></p>"
html_label = HTMLText(window, html=html_sample)
html_label.place(
        x=269.0,
        y=331.0,
        width=426.0,
        height=178.0)
window.mainloop()
```

sometimes I make edits to the HTML text displayed when I run my script, my question is, is there a way to capture the edited HTML?

Here is what I tried so far:

I tried to pass the HTMLText to a `Tkinter` Text widget and use `.get()` method to capture the Text widget output, but the HTMLText never gets displayed, instead, I get `.!frame` in the Text field

Answer (score 1):

If you are asking how you extract the text from the widget, you can use the same method you would with a regular `tkinter` `Text` widget.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkhtmlview import HTMLText
window = Tk()
html_sample = "<p><strong>in love (with </strong>someone or something<strong>)</strong></p>"
html_label = HTMLText(window, html=html_sample)
html_label.pack()
contents = html_label.get('1.0',END)
print(contents)
window.mainloop()
```

output:

```
in love (with someone or something )
```

If instead you are asking to extract the markup that you input into the widget as a parameter, then you can simply subclass the widget and store it in a instance attribute.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkhtmlview import HTMLText

window = Tk()

class MyHTMLText(HTMLText):
    def __init__(self, *args, html=None, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, html=html, **kwargs)
        self.HTML = html


html_sample = "<p><strong>in love (with </strong>someone or something<strong>)</strong></p>"
html_label = MyHTMLText(window, html=html_sample)
html_label.pack()
print(html_label.HTML)
window.mainloop()
```

output

```
<p><strong>in love (with </strong>someone or something<strong>)</strong></p>
```

Comment: Yes, I'm looking to return the text with markup. I tried the 2nd part of your answer and it returns the same exact input.

I want to be able to make edits on the GUI and get the markup with the edits. for example: if I run the script and then remove "in love ", and then call `print(html_label.HTML)`  that should return <p><strong>(with </strong>someone or something<strong>)</strong></p>

Comment: @ZZZ  Unfortunately that isn't possible.  The widget takes your html markup and converts it into rich text behind the scenes, then it tosses the markup that you input.  That is why it is necessary to subclass the just to keep a copy of the original html

Comment: @ZZZ for the sake of clarity, what you are asking is possible in the sense that you could probably implement the reverse yourself, but that feature is not bult in to the widget as is.